# Как си и ассемблер работают без операционной системы?

Tags: ассемблер, загрузчик

Здраствуйте, изучал создание загрузчика операционной системы и возник вопрос: а как код, написанный на masm, fasm, nasm, и т.д., а тем более код на си или c++ будут работать во время включения компьютера и передачи управления моему коду, написанному на этих языках?

Comment: Не очень понятно, какой смысл вы вкладываете в вопрос «как». Прошивка компьютера (например, BIOS или UEFI) считывает ваш машинный код из заранее согласованного места (например, первые 440 байт в MBR или файлик в ESP-разделе) и просто запускает его, а дальше уже делайте что хотите. Компьютеру вообще без разницы, на каком языке вы пишете, главное чтобы в итоге получился машинный код, который компьютер способен выполнить

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/173705/ - здесь я читал о том, как создать загрузчик и у меня появился вопрос, как этот код должен запустится, если он не скомпилирован? Или этот код компилируется в бинарник, а только потом размещается в загрузочном секторе?

Comment: Ну да, там же внизу есть раздел «Давайте соберем все» с командами для компиляции всего этого добра

Comment: Но .COM файлы - это простая программа для DOS, разве нет?

Comment: в любом случае, спасибо, что ответили.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, в данном случае .COM файл — это просто кусок голого машинного кода, не имеющий никакого отношения к DOS. Гляньте [английский оригинал статьи](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36907/How-to-develop-your-own-Boot-Loader), там картинок побольше. В конце статьи есть картинка записи загрузчика на диск, и там в «Hex values» показано содержимое загрузчика. Обратите внимание, что в первых пяти байтах записано `EB 01 90 FA 8C` — это и есть те самые инструкции `jmp short`, `nop`, `cli` и `mov`, записанные в файле `StartPoint.asm`

Comment: Посмотрите на [формат .COM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.COM). Файл в этом формате в самом начале содержит просто инструкции процессора, настроенные линкером на адрес CS:0x100. Поэтому начальному загрузчику (обычно он размещается производителем процессора в ROM) достаточно  просто прочесть файл в память, настроить регистр CS и сделать jmp по адресу CS:0x100. Далее процессор начнет исполнять команды из этого файла.

Comment: @avp машинный код на скриншоте из английской статьи почему-то выполняет jmp на адрес 0x003. Мы вдвоём чего-то не понимаем?

Comment: @andreymal, я не смотрел эти скриншоты, а смотрел в вике. Там написано про CS:0x100. (а переход по нечетному адресу это как-то странно выглядит (правда, последние 5 лет я имел дело исключительно с ARM))

Comment: @avp есть подозрение, что ключик `/T` / `/TINY` в link.exe творит какую-то магию, но у меня не получается нагуглить документацию к нему

Comment: @andreymal, да и с виндой я дело не имею, постоянно юзаю linux с gcc. Там для таких целей надо писать свой так называемый linker-script, описывающий структуру модуля, и передавать его линкеру

Comment: @andreymal Под DOS .com-файл действительно начинал выполнение с адреса 0x100, потому что перед ним лежал блок с данными для запуска, забыл уж, как он назывался (PSP, что ли). Из-за этого в .com-файле не нужны никакие релокейшены, а потому он не мог быть больше 64 килобайт. Загрузчик же грузится из MBR по определенному адресу, 0x7C00, что ли... Опять же не помню точно. И ему передается управление без всякого смещения. `org 0h`, грубо говоря, но он точно знает, в каком месте в памяти находится. А дальше уже его дело затянуть в память и выполнять, что надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опишу, как это было во времена BIOS, что с UEFI, я не знаю.

Это код скомпилированный где-то в машинные коды, и записанный уже в виде машинных кодов в первый сектор первого диска (MasterBootRecord). BIOS при запуске машины считывал этот код в точно определенное место в памяти (0x7C00, что ли... не помню точно) и передавал ему управление. При этом процессор находится в real mode.

А дальше уже дело этого загрузчика затянуть в память коды из других мест на диске и выполнять их, в конечном итоге загружая операционную систему.

Очевидно, что ничего, кроме прерываний BIOS, такой загрузчик использовать не мог.